# Bubble sort not working with local array in assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm32

I'm trying to create a bubble sort with assembly. I've done so successfully with nearly identical code, only now I'm passing in a `LOCAL` array instead of one defined in the `.data` section. Everything runs, but there seems to be no switching.

Here is the code

```
start

call main

exit


main PROC
    LOCAL numArray[5]:DWORD    ; Create a local array for the numbers

    mov [numArray + 0], 5
    mov [numArray + 4], 4
    mov [numArray + 8], 3
    mov [numArray + 12], 2
    mov [numArray + 16], 1

    push numArray
    call BubbleSort

    ret

main ENDP

array EQU [ebp + 8]
FLAG EQU DWORD PTR [ebp - 4]
BubbleSort PROC
    enter 4, 0                      ; Enter with one int local memory (for flag)


    outer_bubble_loop:
        mov ecx, 1                  ; Set the count to 1 
        mov FLAG, 0                 ; And clear the flag (Detects if anything changes

        inner_bubble_loop:                  ; Loop through all values
            mov ebx, [array + ecx * 4 - 4]  ; Move the (n - 1)th index to ebx
            cmp ebx, [array + ecx * 4]      ; Compare ebx against the (n)th index
            jle end_loop                    ; If the result was less than or equal, skip the swapping part


            mov ebx, [array + ecx * 4]      ; Move (n)     into ebx
            mov edx, [array + ecx * 4 - 4]  ; Move (n - 1) into edx
            mov [array + ecx * 4], edx      ; Move (n - 1) into n
            mov [array + ecx * 4 - 4], ebx  ; Move (n)     into (n - 1)
            mov FLAG, 1                     ; Set the changed flag

            end_loop:                       ; End loop label

            inc ecx                         ; Increase the count
            cmp ecx, NDATES                 ; Check if we've made it to the end yet

            jl inner_bubble_loop            ; If not, repeat the inner loop

        cmp FLAG, 0                 ; Check if we changed anything
        je loop_end                 ; If we didn't, go to the end
        jmp outer_bubble_loop       ; (Else) Jump to the beginning of the loop


        loop_end:                   ; Loop end label

    leave
    ret
BubbleSort ENDP
```

My output is, strangely:

> 4
>   5
>   5
>   2
>   1

If I use a different data set, it doesn't do the duplication, but things still aren't moved.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: In my old version of Masm the `LOCAL` directive is used only within a macro, to force the macro to generate unique identifiers for any labels within the macro (so they are not duplicated in other usage of the macro).

Comment: @WeatherVane, from *Assembly Language for x86 Processors, 6th Edition*, "We can guess that Microsoft created the LOCAL directive as a high-level substitute for the ENTER instruction. LOCAL declares one or more local variables by name, assigning them size attributes. (ENTER, on the other hand, only reserves a single unnamed block of stack space for local variables.)" Also, the examples never indicate it can only be used in macros. Actually, they never even show them with macros.

Comment: as weather vane said use

Comment: @David indeed, my Masm uses `ENTER` (and `LEAVE`) to set up a stack frame for local variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane, with the alternative being, according to the book, to just use `LOCAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; push numArray
lea eax, numArray
push eax
call BubbleSort
...
```

... unless I'm mistaken...

Edit: Ahhh... worse than that. I think you're going to have to "dereference" it in BubbleSort, too.

```
mov edx, array ; [ebp + 8], right?
; then use edx instead of "array"... or so...
```

Edit2 ; Whoops, you're already using edx in the swap. Use esi or edi, then...

Comment: Thank you! I had had it dereferencing before, but it wasn't working. Lack of `lea` was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `ret` after the call to `BubbleSort`. I am unsure where you are setting `BP` for the stack frame indexing, but when falling through to the second execution of `BubbleSort` the stack won't be aligned the same.

```
call BubbleSort
ret
```

Or exit the code execution.

Comment: Both are there, just forgot to put them when I condensed my code.

Comment: The program isn't crashing, it's just not sorting.

Comment: I don't suppose that with `mov [numArray + 0], 5` where there is no mention of `BP` that this is going in the data segment?

Comment: In the code given, nothing is pulled from the `.data` segment.